# Comparator for template class objects, C++

Tags: c++, templates, comparator

Let us have the new user type Tlist represented by the set of template objects:

```
template <class T>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::set <Object <T>, sortByVal >   TObjects;     
};
```

Must be the comparator sortByVal also template class or it is sufficient a template method of the non-template class?

```
class sortByVal 
{
    public:
        template <class T>
        bool operator() ( const Object  <T> &o1, const Object  <T> &o2 ) const
        {
            return o1.getVal() < o2.getVal();
        }
};
```

or

```
template <class T>
class sortByVal 
{
    public:
        bool operator() ( const Object  <T> &o1, const Object  <T> &o2 ) const
        {
            return o1.getVal() < o2.getVal();
        }
};
```

Comment: It's called a _class template_, because it's a template from which classes are created, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it one way or the other, it's a matter of taste.

However, in the second case, you should use it like this:

```
typedef std::set <Object <T>, sortByVal<T> >   TObjects;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move comparator to TList class.
And since it has no state, it's simpler to make it a static function:

```
template<typename T>
struct TList
{
    static bool Compare(const TObject<T> &o1,const TObject<T> &o2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use the templated member function, because what's the point of writing `<T>` every time you want to refer to it?